# How can I get the icon corresponding to a file's type in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file, icons, file-type

I need to get the icons associated with file *types* not the file *name*.

I store in my database files with the type=> filename.type, but those files need not exist on the hard disk.

Therefore I need to pass the type and get the icon for it

- I do not want to use solutions with administrative rights needed by the user.
- If possible only managed code
- If possible don't involve registry access

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`SHGetFileInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762179%28VS.85%29.aspx).

If the file does not exist then you will need to use the `SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES` flag:

> If the uFlags parameter includes the
>   SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES flag, this
>   parameter does not have to be a valid
>   file name. The function will proceed
>   as if the file exists with the
>   specified name and with the file
>   attributes passed in the
>   dwFileAttributes parameter. This
>   allows you to obtain information about
>   a file type by passing just the
>   extension for pszPath and passing
>   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL in
>   dwFileAttributes.

As usual, [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.SHGetFileInfo) has the necessary information to get to this from managed code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Win32 API **SHGetFileInfo**, but I think the file should exist for it to work.